# ReferenceError : Page-content not defined, Jquery ajax method

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have two files index.html(local file in hard drive as a part of web app) and just.txt(on local server)
When I send an ajax request the contents in just.txt should be displayed in an alert box.
Here is what I have in index.html

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url:"http://localhost/ajaxtest/just.txt",
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response);
                $("#container").html(response);
            }
        });
});
```

and just.txt includes a single line

```
Hello
```

When I open index.html I get the following error

> ReferenceError: Hello is not defined

where Hello is the only word in just.txt file. I neither get an alert box nor the #container is changed.

But when I put both these files on the local server the issue is solved and I get the alert box saying Hello and the #container is also modified.

I don't want to do this as index.html is a web app file which must be stored locally and just.txt is a file that must be stored in an external server.

Comment: Remove `dataType: 'jsonp',` of `ajax`

Comment: Removing that line leads me to this error
`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost/ajaxtest/just.txt. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.`

Comment: `http://localhost/ajaxtest/just.txt` this is the ajax url. and what is your application's page url. is it different like `http://localhost:3000/bla/bla`

Comment: You need to learn what JSONP format is. You do not just set the parameter and magically works. It requires a call back function.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Comment: @Jai It is a part of a packaged app and is not a hosted application and it is locally stored in hard drive or any other mobile devices in its memory so the application page url would be something like
`file:///root/Desktop/ajaxtest/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The just.txt file must return the data as a function argument and that function must be present in the index.html file.
i.e the just.txt must be like

```
mycallback("Hello")
```

and the index.html file must have a function named mycallback()

```
function mycallback(data)
{
        alert(data);
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url:"http://localhost/ajaxtest/just.txt",
        dataType: 'jsonp'
    });
});
```

so that when a request is send to the just.txt file the function call is returned and it invokes the mycallback function in index.html file and the data is alerted.

Answer (score 0):

Use `dataType : 'text'` instead of `dataType : 'json'`

With 'json' as dataType javascript tries to parse loaded content as JSON and throws an exception

Comment: changing datatype to text create the same cross server error.